# Tomcat complaining about argument types in .schedule()

Tags: tomcat, grails, scheduler

My BootStrap.groovy (Grails 2.5.6) says:

```
AutoKbartUrlUpdateJob.schedule(grailsApplication.config.ygor.autoUpdateJobsInterval, params)
```

and IDEA IntelliJ is absolutely fine with that, executing the Job without any problems. But when deploying onto the Tomcat server, Tomcat fails to start, saying:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static ygor.AutoKbartUrlUpdateJob.schedule() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.HashMap)
```

I'm using the grails quartz plugin:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:quartz:1.0.2"
```

The QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy adds the receiving method for the Job class (only working in IntelliJ) using

```
// Schedule with job with cron trigger
    mc.'static'.schedule = { String cronExpression, Map params = null ->
        scheduleTrigger(TriggerUtils.buildCronTrigger(jobName, jobGroup, cronExpression), params)
    }
```

How can I fix this so that it is working both, in IntelliJ and on Tomcat? I can't find no information about it using search engine.

If a version for both is not applicable, I would work along using different version, so a Tomcat-only solution would help me as well.

Answer (score -1):

Blind one. I was missing to commit the grails plugin added to BuildConfig.groovy in the version management (git).